# How to embedd a non responsible page into an IFrame and make it "responsible"

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I am making a camera system that controlls all my cameras via a website, but I am having a small issue with the styleing, I currently have 4 boxes where it can be sorted and so on.

But my problem is to make an IFrame fit inside a praent div. The width of the content inside the Iframe is wider then the actual div, and I want to see all the content inside the IFrame contained in my parent element. Right now it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the IFrame need to be scrolled to see the right part of the page, and if I increse width it sticks out, but if I increse the width and then scale it down it can fit, but how can I make it "responsive"?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="draggable" draggable="true"><iframe src="http://ipadress:port/stream"></iframe></div>
    <div class="draggable" draggable="true">2</div>
    <div class="draggable" draggable="true">3</div>
    <div class="draggable" draggable="true">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
}

.draggable {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 700ms ease;
    z-index: 1000;

    iframe {
        transform: rotate(180deg) scale(.85);
        width: 120%;
        height: 120%;
        position:absolute;
        left:-10%;
        top:-10%;
    }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var dragDestIndex;
    var draggedEl;
    var draggedElIndex;
    var rearranging = false;
    var rearrangingDuration = 350;
    var draggableElArr = $('.draggable');


    function arrangeItems(itemEls, columnsCount, containerEl, elHeight) {
      var $containerEl = $(containerEl);

      // Set height of elements
      var elWidth = $containerEl.width() / columnsCount;
      elHeight = elHeight || elWidth;

      for (var i=0; i<itemEls.length; i++) {
        var $item = $(itemEls[i]);
        $item.data('index', i);
        var pos = {
          x: (i%columnsCount),
          y: Math.floor(i/columnsCount)
        };

        $item.css({
          top: pos.y * elHeight + 'px',
          left: pos.x * elWidth + 'px',
          width: 'calc(' + (100 / columnsCount) + '% - 10px)',
          height: 'calc(' + elHeight + 'px - 10px)',
          boxSizing: 'border-box'
        });
      }
    }

    function rearrangeItems(arr, movedItemIndex, destinationIndex) {
      var movedEl = arr.splice(movedItemIndex,1)[0];
      arr.splice(destinationIndex, 0, movedEl);
      return arr;
    };

        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 700) {
            arrangeItems(draggableElArr, 1, $('.content'));
        } else {
            arrangeItems(draggableElArr, 2, $('.content'));
        }

    $('.draggable').on('dragstart', function(e){
      draggedEl = $(this);
      var sortedArr = [];
      for (var i=0; i< draggableElArr.length; i++) {
        var elIndex = $(draggableElArr[i]).data('index');
        sortedArr[elIndex] = draggableElArr[i];
      }
      draggableElArr = sortedArr;
      draggedElIndex = $(this).data('index');
      console.log('dragging element at position ', draggedElIndex);
      $(this).css({opacity: 0, transition: 'all 100ms ease'});
    });

    $('.draggable').on('dragend', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).css({opacity: 1, transition: 'all 700ms ease'});
    });

    $('.draggable').on('dragover', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (rearranging) {
        return;
      }
      var dragDestIndex = $(this).data('index');
      console.log('dragging over position ', dragDestIndex);
      draggedElIndex = draggedEl.data('index');
      if (draggedElIndex !== dragDestIndex) {
        rearranging = true;
        console.log('dragging element at position ', draggedElIndex, ' to new dest at position ', dragDestIndex);
        var rearrangedEls = rearrangeItems(draggableElArr, draggedElIndex, dragDestIndex);
        const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
        if(vw < 700) {
            arrangeItems(rearrangedEls, 1, $('.content'));
        } else {
            arrangeItems(rearrangedEls, 2, $('.content'));
        }
        
        setTimeout(function(){ rearranging = false }, rearrangingDuration);
      }
    });

    $('.draggable').on('drop', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      rearranging = false;
    });
```

I now think the problem is that the page I want to embedd is not responsible, here is the code for the camnera page:

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e; height: 100%">
    <img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 25%);" src="http://ipadress:port/stream" width="640" height="480">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Comment: a code sample would be helpful

Comment: Updated the main post with my code!

Comment: for the frame content, you can something like this `<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e; height: 100%;width:100%;">
    <img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 25%);height: 100%;width:100%;object-fit:contains;" src="http://ipadress:port/stream"  >
</body>
</html>` . You can also use sized grid holding iframes. https://jsfiddle.net/o8azLqp7/ to avoid rezing it on the fly

Comment: see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit to size a video or image inside its container ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Object fit doesnt work, nothing happens, and I cannot really change the camera stream page unfortunaley...